# How to change column delimiter in the exported .csv file of the Concurrency Visualizer Thread View, in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, csv, visual-studio-2012

I need to change the column delimiter character of the .csv exported file of the Concurrency Visualizer Thread View. I'm using C#, in Visual Studio 2012, on Windows 7 Ultimate.

The problem is that the CSV file uses the comma `,` character, to separate the columns, and also in the numbers. This brings confusion to the statistics software, including Microsoft Excel. With this symbol you cannot tell if `2000,22` is a float number or two columns (the first with the `2000` value, and the second with the `22` value). I tried to open these files with Microsoft Excel and SPSS v19, using comma (,) or space as columns delimiter, but I do not get the same table exported from the Concurrency Visualizer.

I'm doing an investigation that requires measuring code block in milliseconds, that is why I'm using the span of the Concurrency Visualizer. I need to statistically process the duration of all the spans, to be sure my code is getting the right results. That is why I am using the CSV export feature, in the Concurrency Visualizer Thread View.

The semicolon character `;` could be a nice column delimiter, because it eliminates the ambiguity.

The CSV file exported by the Concurrency Visualizer Thread View can be a great tool for software investigation, once we solve this.